# moveit demo.launch, rviz initializing forever

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, here is my problem:

I setup my model using the setup assistant of moveit. Everything seems to work. I export the package, save it under src/ in the catkin_ws/. Then I run "roslaunch my_package demo.launch" .

Here the process starts until the terminal says in green " You can start planning now! " The RViz initializing picture is freezed forever.

However, I get in the terminal  "[INFO] [1498661559]: MoveGroup context initialization complete".

What do you think about that? is my PC not strong enough or do I have another problem?
Thank you in advance,
Stefano

Details:

-I can run RViz stand-alone, no problem.

-I am using a 4 years old laptop, intel i3 quadcore 2.53GHz, geforce 610M.

-I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed by a friend's usb flashkey

-can I run gazebo if the grafics drivers are not installed?

Complete terminal:

```
    zampieri@zampieri-Hack:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch moveit_config_complete_arm_3 demo.launch 
... logging to /home/zampieri/.ros/log/8bbb4536-5bd0-11e7-b431-7ce9d3541a7d/roslaunch-zampieri-Hack-26924.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://zampieri-Hack:45617/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /joint_state_publisher/use_gui: False
 * /move_group/allow_trajectory_execution: True
 * /move_group/arm/longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.005
 * /move_group/arm/planner_configs: ['SBLkConfigDefau...
 * /move_group/arm/projection_evaluator: joints(joint_1,jo...
 * /move_group/controller_list: [{'joints': ['joi...
 * /move_group/jiggle_fraction: 0.05
 * /move_group/max_range: 5.0
 * /move_group/max_safe_path_cost: 1
 * /move_group/moveit_controller_manager: moveit_fake_contr...
 * /move_group/moveit_manage_controllers: True
 * /move_group/octomap_resolution: 0.025
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/balanced: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/cache_cc: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/extended_fmt: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/heuristics: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/nearest_k: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/num_samples: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/optimality: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BFMT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiESTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BiEST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/cost_threshold: 1e300
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/frountier_node_ratio: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/init_temperature: 100
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/temp_change_factor: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BiTRRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::EST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/cache_cc: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/extended_fmt: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/heuristics: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/nearest_k: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/num_samples: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/radius_multiplier: 1.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::FMT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::KPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LBKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/epsilon: 0.4
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LBTRRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LazyPRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LazyPR...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PDSTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PDST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/max_nearest_neighbors: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRMstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjESTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjESTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::ProjEST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTCon...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/delay_collision_checking: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/type: geometric::SBL
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/max_failures: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/type: geometric::SPARS
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/max_failures: 5000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/type: geometric::SPARStwo
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/degree: 16
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/estimated_dimension: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/max_degree: 18
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/max_pts_per_leaf: 6
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/min_degree: 12
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.2
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::STRIDE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/use_projected_distance: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/frountierNodeRatio: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/init_temperature: 10e-6
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/k_constant: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/max_states_failed: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/min_temperature: 10e-10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/temp_change_factor: 2.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::TRRT
 * /move_group/planning_plugin: ompl_interface/OM...
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_geometry_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_state_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_transforms_updates: True
 * /move_group/request_adapters: default_planner_r...
 * /move_group/start_state_max_bounds_error: 0.1
 * /move_group/tool/planner_configs: ['SBLkConfigDefau...
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_execution_duration_scaling: 1.2
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_goal_duration_margin: 0.5
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_start_tolerance: 0.01
 * /robot_description: <...>
 * /robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_1/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_1/has_velocity_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_1/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_1/max_velocity: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_2/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_2/has_velocity_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_2/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_2/max_velocity: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_3/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_3/has_velocity_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_3/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_3/max_velocity: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_4/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_4/has_velocity_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_4/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_4/max_velocity: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_5/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_5/has_velocity_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_5/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_5/max_velocity: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_6/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_6/has_velocity_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_6/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_6/max_velocity: 0
 * /robot_description_semantic: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7
 * /rviz_zampieri_Hack_26924_1366369051882570045/arm/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /rviz_zampieri_Hack_26924_1366369051882570045/arm/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /rviz_zampieri_Hack_26924_1366369051882570045/arm/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /rviz_zampieri_Hack_26924_1366369051882570045/arm/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /source_list: ['/move_group/fak...

NODES
  /
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    rviz_zampieri_Hack_26924_1366369051882570045 (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[joint_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [26943]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [26944]
process[move_group-3]: started with pid [26945]
process[rviz_zampieri_Hack_26924_1366369051882570045-4]: started with pid [26955]
[ INFO] [1498670592.455818693]: Loading robot model 'complete_arm_3'...
[ INFO] [1498670592.606691324]: rviz version 1.12.4
[ INFO] [1498670592.606805486]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1498670592.606836539]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1498670592.746379300]: Loading robot model 'complete_arm_3'...
[ INFO] [1498670593.452864933]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1498670593.457962988]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
Starting context monitors...
[ INFO] [1498670593.458044252]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1498670593.462689552]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1498670593.462749903]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1498670593.470221078]: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/base_link '
[ INFO] [1498670593.476381511]: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[ INFO] [1498670593.577253169]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1498670593.577445788]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5).
[ INFO] [1498670594.107316374]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
Context monitors started.
[ INFO] [1498670594.194333668]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ INFO] [1498670594.273044640]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[ INFO] [1498670594.324989399]: Param 'default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10
[ INFO] [1498670594.326292634]: Param 'start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.1
[ INFO] [1498670594.327329008]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1498670594.328605490]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1498670594.329608009]: Param 'jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.05
[ INFO] [1498670594.330761821]: Param 'max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[ INFO] [1498670594.330875370]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Parameterization'
[ INFO] [1498670594.330927659]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[ INFO] [1498670594.330961864]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[ INFO] [1498670594.330988864]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[ INFO] [1498670594.331017475]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[ INFO] [1498670594.388064804]: Fake controller 'fake_arm_controller' with joints [ joint_1 joint_2 joint_3 joint_4 joint_5 joint_6 ]
[ INFO] [1498670594.388886822]: Fake controller 'fake_tool_controller' with joints [ ]
[ INFO] [1498670594.389720156]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1498670594.414805552]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[ INFO] [1498670594.647013163]: 

********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1498670594.647160120]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1498670594.647450439]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

You can start planning now!
```

Here is the demo.launch :

```
<launch>

  <!-- By default, we do not start a database (it can be large) -->
  <arg name="db" default="false" />
  <!-- Allow user to specify database location -->
  <arg name="db_path" default="$(find moveit_config_complete_arm_4)/default_warehouse_mongo_db" />

  <!-- By default, we are not in debug mode -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false" />

  <!-- Load the URDF, SRDF and other .yaml configuration files on the param server -->
  <include file="$(find moveit_config_complete_arm_4)/launch/planning_context.launch">
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <!-- If needed, broadcast static tf for robot root -->
  

  <!-- We do not have a robot connected, so publish fake joint states -->
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="/source_list">[/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>

  <!-- Given the published joint states, publish tf for the robot links -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="true" output="screen" />

  <!-- Run the main MoveIt executable without trajectory execution (we do not have controllers configured by default) -->
  <include file="$(find moveit_config_complete_arm_4)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="allow_trajectory_execution" value="true"/>
    <arg name="fake_execution" value="true"/>
    <arg name="info" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Run Rviz and load the default config to see the state of the move_group node -->
  <include file="$(find moveit_config_complete_arm_4)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- If database loading was enabled, start mongodb as well -->
  <include file="$(find moveit_config_complete_arm_4)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" if="$(arg db)">
    <arg name="moveit_warehouse_database_path" value="$(arg db_path)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265030/moveit-demo.launch,-rviz-initializing-forever/) by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:
Can you run RViz stand-alone? What sort of hardware are you using? A regular desktop PC, a raspberry pi, something else? Which Linux version is this, how did you install it, do you have the graphics drivers for your video card installed? Please *edit* your question and add these details.

**Comment by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on 2017-06-28**:
I made my robot model using the setup assistant as well. The next message I get after the "You can start planning now" is "loading robot model mybot". So maybe there is something wrong with your robot model. Did you write the urdf file yourself? Have you successfully included it in setup assistant?

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-28**:
@gvdhoorn: Thanks for guiding my question. I updated it.

@Felix : Yeah, I dont get "loading robot model mybot". I made the urdf file using the SolidWorks plug-in "export to urdf". I included it successfully in the setup assistant, i can move my joints and see my model. How ever I have some warnings

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-28**:
I corrected the errors in the warnings. I have no more warnings. Still no response from RViz. I hope i don't have to reinstall ros ^^.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:\

> can I run gazebo if the grafics drivers are not installed

sometimes. It won't run very well, but it'll probably produce some image.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:
It might help if you copy-paste the complete terminal output into your question (use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it)). Can you tell us anything about the model you're trying to load? How big are the meshes? If they are too detailed, loading can be very slow.

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-28**:
in the options within the SlidWorks plug-in I could choose corse meshes or fine meshes. I choose fine...  How ever I dont get until the "loading robot model mybot" phase (see terminal in the updated question). In addition i left my computer loading for 3-4 hours with no results.

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-28**:
I am going to try anyway with a corse meshing. I keep you updated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:
This has probably nothing to do with your problem, but:

> MoveGroup debug mode is ON

did you enable this yourself?

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-28**:
nope, I did not enable anything. how to disable it?

I now tried with a corse mesh but the result is the same.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
Well, by default `debug:=false` in `demo.launch`, so I'm wondering how it says 'ON' if that hasn't changed. Can you check `demo.launch`?

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-29**:
I updated the question with the demo.launch. It seems ok " debug="false".

Now when I `roslaunch` the `demo.launch` I have to more lines in the terminal (in addition to the terminal I posted). One is saying `[INFO] [1498722837.712557891]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
Again: this is probably not the cause of your problem, but I'm just curious now.

And in `move_group.launch`?

Does the output change if you start it like: `roslaunch <your_moveit_cfg> demo.launch debug:=false`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
As for your rviz problem: try commenting the part in `demo.launch` that starts RViz (second to last `include`). Then start `demo.launch`. If that is successful, keep it running, then in a separate terminal, start just `rviz`. Does that work? If so, try adding the MoveIt RViz display.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:\

> geforce 610M

does your laptop have two graphics cards by any chance? So it's using 'nvidia optimus technology'? If so, that could be a problem. Do you have that setup correctly (ie: installed necessary drivers)? Try disabling the Intel video card, just to rule things out.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
Btw: an i3 with a geforce 610M is rather low-specced. It's probably possible to get things to run, but for any real use of RViz, Gazebo and / or MoveIt it's probably going to be a tad slow.

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-29**:\

- in `move_group.launch` debug is false
- the output is the same adding `debug:=false` at the end of the command
- I commented the part which starts RViz, the demo.launch runs successfully. Then in another terminal I run RViz. It is working.

What is the MoveIt RViz display?

**Comment by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) on 2017-06-29**:
Yeah I have nvidia optimus tech. I'll try to disable the Intel video card (I have no Idea how to do such things ^^).
Maybe I should install linux in my new laptop which is way more powerful and have only one graphics card.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:\

> What is the MoveIt RViz display?

Please see [wiki/rviz/UserGuide - Displays](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Displays).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:\

> Maybe I should install linux in my new laptop which is way more powerful and have only one graphics card.

that will most likely simplify things significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys the problem was the nvidia optimus as gvdhoorn said. I switched the driver from "nvidia binary driver" to "Nouveau display driver (open source)".
Now it works fine. So the file were not the problem. Thanks again for your help. It makes things really easier. Have a good day <3

---

Originally posted by [stefano](https://answers.ros.org/users/30948/stefano/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-30**:
If you have the chance -- and the perseverance -- I would really recommend you try to figure out a way to get optimus to work properly: the nouveau drivers really don't cut it when you start working with any 'real' ROS applications, especially not when you start visualising a lot of data in RViz.